# pipenv install spawns thousands of python.exe processes

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, python-3.7

EDIT: see https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1380 for confirmed bug

when running `pipenv install` I'm seeing thousands of python.exe processes being started, it never stops.

```
C:\Users\dangel>tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /C "python.exe"
94

C:\Users\dangel>tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /C "python.exe"
105

C:\Users\dangel>tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /C "python.exe"
202

C:\Users\dangel>tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /C "python.exe"
400

C:\Users\dangel>tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /C "python.exe"
826
```

I tried the following...

- uninstalling python
- deleting C:\Users\dangel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python
- deleting C:\Users\dangel\AppData\Local\pip
- deleting C:\Users\dangel\AppData\Local\pipenv
- deleting C:\Users\dangel\.virtualenvs
- deleting anything in C:\Users\dangel\AppData\Local\Temp that mentioned pip, pipenv, or python

and then after that....

- Re-installed Python 3.7
- `pip install pipenv`
- `C:\Users\dangel>mkdir pipenvtest`
- `C:\Users\dangel>cd pipenvtest`
- `C:\Users\dangel\pipenvtest>pipenv shell`

and same thing...  constant spawning of python.exe processes

Is there some other cache\temp folder that I'm missing that I should clear out to see if it's causing an issue?

I just recently updated to Python 3.7.4 a few days ago... But I've been having trouble using PyCharm with pipenv for a while, so I'm no stranger to having to having issues with pipenv, just nothing this serious.

Comment: I know believe this to be a python 3.7.4 bug.  I've been able to duplicate it on a brand new intall